# Rails having a naming error on a form_for that is causing an unknown path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The issue is I get this nasty little controller error...
NoMethodError in Contacts#new
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#:0x0000000124b228>
 Did you mean?  contact_path

on my view: contact#new

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

<div class="col-xs-6 form-group contact-input">
<h1><%= f.label :Feedback %></h1>
<%= f.text_area :text, class: "input-lg form-control", rows: "10" %>

<%= f.submit "Send Feedback", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

controller: contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to '/'
      flash[:success] = "Thanks for the Post!"
    else
      redirect_to contact_path
      flash[:alert] = "Please provide input!"
    end
  end
end
```

migration:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|

      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The error is complaining about line 3 in the view. My model is contact.rb incase I have a plural issue somewhere, but I really do not think that I do. Any help would be much appreciated. This is rails 4.2...  I am also a rails beginner.

I know I don't have the flash even setup yet.

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
              root GET    /                                             static_pages#home
             about GET    /about(.:format)                              static_pages#about
              news GET    /news(.:format)                               static_pages#news
         advertise GET    /advertise(.:format)                          static_pages#advertise
           fishing GET    /fishing(.:format)                            static_pages#fishing
            signup GET    /signup(.:format)                             users#new
             users GET    /users(.:format)                              users#index
                   POST   /users(.:format)                              users#create
          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                          users#new
         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                     users#edit
              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#show
                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                          users#destroy
           contact GET    /contact(.:format)                            contacts#new
     contact_index GET    /contact(.:format)                            contact#index
                   POST   /contact(.:format)                            contact#create
       new_contact GET    /contact/new(.:format)                        contact#new
      edit_contact GET    /contact/:id/edit(.:format)                   contact#edit
                   GET    /contact/:id(.:format)                        contact#show
                   PATCH  /contact/:id(.:format)                        contact#update
                   PUT    /contact/:id(.:format)                        contact#update
                   DELETE /contact/:id(.:format)                        contact#destroy
    forum_comments GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                   POST   /forums/:forum_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                   PATCH  /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                   PUT    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                   DELETE /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            forums GET    /forums(.:format)                             forums#index
                   POST   /forums(.:format)                             forums#create
         new_forum GET    /forums/new(.:format)                         forums#new
        edit_forum GET    /forums/:id/edit(.:format)                    forums#edit
             forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#show
                   PATCH  /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#update
                   PUT    /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#update
                   DELETE /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#destroy
            logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                             sessions#destroy
          sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                           sessions#create
       new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                       sessions#new
```

routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'about' =>      'static_pages#about'
  get 'news' =>       'static_pages#news'
  get 'advertise' =>  'static_pages#advertise'
  get 'fishing' =>    'static_pages#fishing'

  get 'signup' =>     'users#new'
  resources :users

  get 'contact' =>    'contacts#new'
  resources :contact

  resources :forums do
    resources :comments
  end

  delete 'logout' =>     'sessions#destroy'
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create] 
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` and the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: I added them, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `resources :contact` to `resources :contacts` in your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot and thanks to Zepplock just thinking about my routes showed my problem. The get 
  get 'contact' =>    'contacts#new'
was the problem I had. I also switched my resources :contact to :contacts. All my issues were solved. Thanks for asking for the right stuff again Zepplock!